R shiny app won't render plots until all multiple tabs was clicked
I built a simple R shiny app with multiple tabs. When I run the app, the plot on each tab would not show when I first clicked on each of the tabs. An error message shows attempt to select less than one element in get1index. However, after I clicked on each of the tabs until the last tab, plots started to show up on each tab without error message. The order of  does not matter  Following is the screenshot I have when I run the app. Would you please kindly point out which direction I should pursue to solve this issue? Thanks,
Before I clicked on each of the tabs, I got the following ERROR message with no plot rendered.

After I clicked on each of the tabs, starting from the last tab I clicked, all plots start to show up.

The core part of UI and server of R shiny app was extracted as following.
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("EMR Comparative Analysis"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Overall Comparison",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 # Radio button to select between EMR Site and EMR Form
                 radioButtons(
                   inputId = "overall_comparison_type",
                   label = "Select comparison type:",
                   choices = c("EMR Site" = "emrsite", "EMR Form" = "emrform"),
                   selected = "emrsite"
                 ),
                 # Dropdown menu for study selection
                 uiOutput("overallStudySelectInput"),
                 # Input selection for cumulative daily time series
                 uiOutput("overallMetricSelectInput")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("overallPlot")
               )
             )
    ),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Monthly Comparison",
...
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {


# Consolidate reactive expressions for data selection
  selectedData <- reactive({
    print("Running selectedData() reactive...")
    
    list(
      cumulative = {
        # req(input$cumulative_comparison_type, input$select_cumulative_study, input$select_cumulative_metric)
        print("Fetching cumulative data...")
        data_list <- get(input$cumulative_comparison_type)
        study_data <- data_list[[input$select_cumulative_study]]
        print(paste("Selected study for cumulative TS:", input$select_cumulative_study))
        kpi_data <- study_data[[input$select_cumulative_metric]]
      },
      monthly = {
        # req(input$select_monthly_study, input$select_monthly_metric)
        print("Fetching monthly data...")
        data_list <- get(input$monthly_comparison_type)
        study_data <- data_list[[input$select_monthly_study]]
        print(paste("Selected study for monthly TS:", input$select_monthly_study))
        kpi_data <- study_data[[input$select_monthly_metric]]
      },
      overall = {
        # req(input$select_overall_study, input$select_overall_metric)
        print("Fetching overall data...")
        data_list <- get(input$overall_comparison_type)
        study_data <- data_list[[input$select_overall_study]]
        print(paste("Selected study for overall TS:", input$select_overall_study))
        kpi_data <- study_data[[input$select_overall_metric]]
      }
    )
  })
  # Render overall Plot
  output$overallPlot <- renderPlot({
    data <- selectedData()$overall
    
    print("overall data structure:")
    print(str(data))
    
    comparison_var <- if (input$overall_comparison_type == "emrsite") {
      "is_emr_site"
    } else {
      "is_emr_form"
    }
    
    comparison_label <- c(
      "Yes" = if (input$overall_comparison_type == "emrsite") "EMR Sites" else "EMR Forms",
      "No" = if (input$overall_comparison_type == "emrsite") "Non-EMR Sites" else "Non-EMR Forms"
    )
    
    data[[comparison_var]] <- factor(data[[comparison_var]], levels = names(comparison_label), labels = comparison_label)
    
    # Identify columns starting with 'ratio' or 'duration_median'
    plot_var <- grep("^ratio|^duration_median", names(data), value = TRUE)
    
    ggplot(data, aes_string(x = comparison_var, y = plot_var, fill = comparison_var)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
      labs(title = "Overall Comparison by Study", x = "EMR vs. Non-EMR", y = "Overall Ratio/Median", fill = "Comparison Group") +
      theme_minimal()
  })
...
}

# Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)

I have tried the following changes.

I tried to change the order of the tabs or the order of clicking on the tabs. It is the same issue no matter how I order the tabs on UI and server.
I tried to simplify the input data structure from nested list to less nested list. It did not work.
I asked ChatGPT. Still cannot figure out the root cause.


You should always provide a minimal, reproducible example and not a "core part" containing several "...".

You need to provide selectedData() + there's a problem in the ui part with missing ")" & the tabs are not in the same tabsetPanel.

@Jan Thank you for your comment!  I should have provided the minimal reproducible example. However, I really do not know which part of the code I should leave out and how to get the nested list as input of the example. Sorry for the inconvenience.

@thekangaroofactory thank you for pointing out the issue with the reactive expression selectedData()$overall etc! Over the past two days, I slowly realized that it might be the cause of the delay in rendering since I wrapped the inputs of multiple tabs into one list as the output of selectedData() reactive expression. I tried to unwrap the list that selectedData() produces, and the delay of the rendering in plots on multiple tabs finally disappeared.

As you can see in the plot output, there is an error:

Attempt to select less than one element in get1index

This error is generated while trying to build the renderPlot() expression.
So the problem is not linked to Shiny.
The reason why the behavior is different when you click one tab and then come back is because something different happens the second time.
It very likely that the error comes from this line:
data[[comparison_var]] <- factor(data[[comparison_var]], levels = names(comparison_label), labels = comparison_label)

For example LETTERS[[NULL]] will produce this error.
I would suggest to check the init phase when input$overall_comparison_type may be NULL.

When I used browser(), then `print()' to debug, I still cannot locate where NULL value come from.

Thank you for pointing out the direction, @thekangaroofactory! I have fixed part of the original issue. Initially, I have to click on all tabs until I reached the last tab for the plots to be rendered in each tab. I changed the selectedData() reactive expression and broke down the reactive expression to multiple reactive corresponding to each plot in each tab. It solved the delaying of rendering plots across tabs. However, the ERROR message of attempt to select less than one element in get1index, still persists for the first time I clicked on each tab. The ERROR message will flash for less than half second before plots render. After the initial rendering of the plots, the error message does not show up anymore when I make selections on the study level or KPI level. My revised code which solved the first part of the issue is following. Of course, I also have to revise all corresponding part in renderPlot() accordingly.
## Debug plot render issue: Unwrap data selection from a list of reactive expression
  cumulative_data <- reactive({
    data_list <- get(input$cumulative_comparison_type)
    study_data <- data_list[[input$select_cumulative_study]]
    kpi_data <- study_data[[input$select_cumulative_metric]]
    })
  
  monthly_data <- reactive({
    data_list <- get(input$monthly_comparison_type)
    study_data <- data_list[[input$select_monthly_study]]
    kpi_data <- study_data[[input$select_monthly_metric]]
    })
        
  overall_data <- reactive({
    data_list <- get(input$overall_comparison_type)
    study_data <- data_list[[input$select_overall_study]]
    kpi_data <- study_data[[input$select_overall_metric]]
    })

